# Declaring a string in C# vs VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net

In the middle of attaching a Google Custom Search Engine onto my page,

I have a string which I would declare in C# as

String rxPattern = "<(?>\"[^\"]*\"|'[^']*'|[^'\">])*>";

How do I convert it to a string in VB?
I mean store the same value into the string variable rxPattern using VB/VB.NET?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace your `\"` with `""` (double-double quotes) and get rid of the semi-colon:

```
Dim rxPattern As String = "<(?>""[^""]""|'[^']'|[^'"">])*>"
```